# Nativescript-vue issue with list in GridLayout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm fairly new to natviescript, I'm using GridLayout to try to avoid layout nesting to the max for better performance, in my template I have an image and then I have a vertical list of four items right next to my image, however only the first item list is showing up, the others are falling out of my the GridLayout bonds, how can I get the other list items to appear right below the first one.

My template:

```
<GridLayout width="100%" height="175px" rows="auto,auto,auto,auto" columns="auto,*,20" backgroundColor="green" style="padding:10px 10px;">
    <Image row="0" column="0" src="res://logo" loadMode="async" stretch="aspectFit" style="background-color:red; width:175px; height:175px; border-radius:10px; margin:0px 20px 0px 0px;"></Image>
    <Label text="Pacome1" fontSize="18" row="0" column="1" class="c_light" style="margin:5px 0px;"></Label>
    <Label text="Pacome2" fontSize="18" row="1" column="1" class="c_light" style="margin:5px 0px;"></Label>
    <Label text="Pacome3" fontSize="18" row="2" column="1" class="c_light" style="margin:5px 0px;"></Label>
    <Label text="Pacome4" fontSize="18" row="3" column="1" class="c_light" style="margin:5px 0px;"></Label>
    <Label :text="'fa-star' | fonticon" row="0" col="2" class="fa c_light fs_small" style="margin:10px 0px;"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: You are using `col` in your icon which is correct term but everywhere else it reads `column`, that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. your last Label has `col` instead of column.
2. `auto` in the `rows`/`columns` field of the grid layout means "let this component take up the space it needs for its dimensions." `*` means "take up the available space remaining." You can also do things like `2*` to say "this item should take up 2 times the remaining space as the other items."

   3. if the components are overflowing the GridLayout then maybe the sum of all your items inside the GridLayout is greater than the height of the GridLayout. Consider settings heights on your labels or increasing the height of your GridLayout.